# How to display only First and Last element of the array with foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have student exam scores in an array and want to show only the first and last exam score when student selects for

how do I show first and last element only of an array with foreach loop in PHP.

so far I have done the below method which works for me but it seems not an efficient method

```
$y = 0; 

$student_total_sessions = $total_counter = sizeof($student_exam_session_data);

if($this->data['show_sessions'] != 'all_sessions')
{
    $student_total_sessions = ($student_total_sessions > 2) ? 2 : $student_total_sessions;
}

foreach ($student_exam_session_data as $student_session_id => $student_session_data) 
{ 
    $y++;
    // only show first and last in case show sessions is pre and post
    if($this->data['show_sessions'] != 'all_sessions' && $y > 1 && $y != $total_counter)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        echo $student_session_data['exam_score'];
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_shift`, `array_pop`

Comment: Try `current` and `end` functions

Comment: `reset()` and `end()`

Comment: Thanks u_mulder I have replaced my array before foreach using array_shift and array_pop

Answer (score 2):

To display the first element of array

```
echo $array[0];//in case of numeric array
echo reset($array);// in case of associative array
```

To display the last element

```
echo $array[count($array)-1];//in case of numeric array
echo end($myArray);// in case of associative array
```

Comment: And if array is __not__ numeric_indexed?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR I need to this inside a foreach loop becuase its upto enduser if want to see all the sessions or first or last. So I want to skip the loop iterations in case end user has selected the first and last sessions to view. I have mentioned this in my question that I need to do this inside foreach loop

Comment: yes you can paste the above code inside the foreach loop, i think your array is multidimensional according to your question

Answer (score 0):

If your array has unique array values, then determining the first and last element is trivial:

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    if ($element === reset($array))
        echo 'FIRST ELEMENT!';

    if ($element === end($array))
        echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```

This works if last and first elements are appearing just once in an array, otherwise you get false positives. Therefore, you have to compare the keys (they are unique for sure).

```
foreach($array as $key => $element) {
    reset($array);
    if ($key === key($array))
        echo 'FIRST ELEMENT!';

    end($array);
    if ($key === key($array))
        echo 'LAST ELEMENT!';
}
```

Comment: This method is still looping through all the elements of the array. How can I skip rest of the iterations in case I need first and last only

Comment: You first need to loop all the values after then check my first example and echo the array 1st value and last value from array. I gave you the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](https://megalomaniacslair.co.uk/php-foreach-first-and-last/) about exactly this a while back. Basically:

```
// Go to start of array and get key, for later comparison
reset($array)
$firstkey = key($array);
// Go to end of array and get key, for later comparison
end($array);
$lastkey = key($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $element) {
  // If first element in array
  if ($key === $firstkey)
    echo 'FIRST ELEMENT = '.$element;

  // If last element in array
  if ($key === $lastkey)
    echo 'LAST ELEMENT = '.$element;
} // end foreach
```

OR for PHP 7.3 and up use `array_key_first` and `array_key_last`:

```
foreach($array as $key => $element) {
  // If first element in array
  if ($key === array_key_first($array))
    echo 'FIRST ELEMENT = '.$element;

  // If last element in array
  if ($key === array_key_last($array))
    echo 'LAST ELEMENT = '.$element;
} // end foreach
```